# Game Strategy Problem

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory

There are 2 players, who we will call A and B. A stack of cards is given initially. It may contain an arbitrary number of cards. A player whose turn comes may take between 1 and 5 cards; how many they take is their choice. Player A begins. The last player who can make a move has won the game. How should the players behave? Is there a strategy by which one of the players can force a win, no matter what the opponent does? How does it depend on the initial numbers of cards? For given numbers of cards, how many rounds must at least be played before the game ends?

Comment: This is known as a [subtraction game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim#The_subtraction_game_S.281.2C_2.2C_._._..2C_k.29).

Answer (score 6):

If $A$ takes $k$ cards and $B$ replies by taking $6-k$ cards, then $B$
will win whenever there are a multiple of $6$ cards at the start.

Suppose the starting number is not a multiple of $6$. What should $A$ do?

Comment: I can't get my head around how to work it out?

Comment: @a.macklin Let's play: start with 15 cards, I'll let you go first.

Comment: I'll take 3 cards then

Comment: @a.macklin Leaving me 12. Hmm. I'll take 2, leaving you 10.

Comment: I'll go for 5 then

Comment: @a.macklin And I'll take all 5 remaining, so I win! And I thought you had me on the ropes for a moment!

Comment: Right!  @a.macklin, if you had taken $4$ cards in your last turn, leaving LStU with $6$, you would have won on your last turn no matter what LStU did.

Comment: So we started with a multiple of 5 - I took 3, you took 5 - 3 = 2, I took 5 and...

Comment: Did I mention multiples of 5?

Comment: Oh, nope, what significance did 15 have on the final outcome though?

Comment: @a.macklin Only that 15 was not a multiple of 6.

Comment: So is there a strategy?

Comment: @a.macklin I presented a winning strategy for B when the initial number of cards is a multiple of 6. I hinted that there is a winning strategy for A otherwise and challenged the reader to find it.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I can't work it out?

Comment: @a.macklin leave a multiple of 6 if you can!

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I see! So if I had left you 13 in our game, you'd take 1 to leave 12, Then whatever I take, you could win? Say I took 2 to leave 10, You could leave any number greater than 5 and win?