# Single Pile Nim proof by Induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

This is the single pile nime game where a player has to take between 1-3 coins out of the pile. I found the pattern and wrote most of the proof, but I cannot really think of a way to prove the inductive step formally. It seems like the circumstances change every time I get to congruence with 0(mod 4) and it can't be universally proven.

[Proof of one pile take away game]
Suppose there are n coins in one pile. If n is not congruent to 0(mod 4), where a is some positive integer, then the first player will always be in the winning position if the pile n is not conguent 0(mod 4). If n is congruent 0(mod 4), then Player 1 will always be in a losing position if played correctly.

{Base cases}: if n=1, 2, or 3, then the pile is not congruent with 0(mod 4). Player 1 is in a winning position, because the player can clear the pile and win. If n=4, the pile is congruent with 0(mod 4). Player 1 has to take 1-3 coins from the pile, which causes the pile n to equal 1, 2, or 3 for Player 2’s turn, and this will be a winning position for Player 2.

{Induction hypothesis}: Now suppose pile k > 3, and assume pile k congruent 0(mod 4) is a losing position for Player 1 and pile k not congruence 0(mod 4) is a winning position for Player 1.

Comment: A related question is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2253411/game-strategy-problem/2253415#2253415

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I have the winning strategy, I just can't think of a formal way to directly prove the inductive step. The wording is just very complicated in my head.

Comment: Why is induction so important here?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown This is part of a big assignment, and I need to be extremely clear and formal in proving that my solution is correct. It's hard to be wordy when the solution is so obvious.

Comment: @AnginaSeng induction is important a.e. in math.  It's as if the proofs which are usually DAG's structurally are broken free from, how?  A loop in the structure graph of the proof.  How do we handle it?  Induction, and then everything becomes a DAG again with inference rules describing how to induct.  At least this is a theory or hunch I'm assuming.

Answer (score 1):

Player 1 has a winning strategy if the original number of coins is not $0($mod$4)$, and player 2 has a winning strategy if the original number of coins is $0($mod$4)$.

Rather than induction, using infinite descent (which is equivalent) would be neater.

Base case: Suppose there are $1, 2$, or $3$ coins. Player one can take all of them, and he wins. If there are $4 = 0($mod$4)$ coins, player 2 wins (as you explained before).

"Inductive" (infinite descent) step:
Suppose there are $k = 0($mod$4)$ coins. Now if player 1 takes $1$ coin in turn one, player 2 will take $3$ coins in turn two. It is now player 1's turn and there are again $0($mod$4)$ coins. Similarly if player 1 takes $2$ or $3$ coins, player 2 will take $2$ or $1$ coin respectively. Thus no matter how many coins player 1 takes on his first turn, he will end up with $0($mod$4)$ coins on his next turn. By the method of infinite descent, after a finite number of turns it will be player 1's turn and only $4$ coins will remain. Thus player 2 will win.

Now suppose there are $k \neq 0($mod$4)$ coins in the starting position. If $k = 1($mod$4)$, player 1 takes 1 coin. If $k = 2($mod$4)$, player 1 takes 2 coins, and if $k = 3($mod$4)$, player 1 takes 3 coins so that on player 2's first turn he has a pile with $0($mod$4)$ coins. By the same reasoning as above, after a finite number of turns, it will be player 2's turn and only $4$ coins will remain. Thus player 1 will win.

Answer (score 1):

On the one hand, I agree with Harambe that descent provides a more elegant argument.  On the other hand, since the OP is specifically focusing on induction...

Induction step: 
Assume that $N$ is a multiple of $4$.
Assume that for all $n \leq N$, $n$ is a losing position (rather than a winning position) for the player about to move, if and only if $n \equiv 0\pmod{4}.$

Consider the 4 situations: 
$\{N+1, N+2, N+3\}.$
$\{N+4\}.$

In the first three situations, it is clear that the player whose move it is, can convert the situation to one with $N$ left, with the other player now having to move.

Therefore, the first three situations are clearly winning for the player whose move it is.

For the 4th situation, $N+4$, the reverse is true.  That is, whatever move you make, the other player will be faced with one of $\{N+1, N+2, N+3\}$, which, by the previous analysis, is winning for the other player.

---

Thus, if the assertion is true for $N$, a multiple of $4$, then the assertion is also true for $N+4$.  That is, if it is true that for all $n \leq N$, $n$ is losing for the player on move if and only if $n \equiv 0\pmod{4}$, then the same assertion must also be true for $N+4$.